# How to validate result set for multiple prepared statement query execution

Tags: java, prepared-statement, javabeans, resultset

I have created a method saveTransaction(ArrayList sessionList), which saves the ItemBean parameters saved in sessionList to the TRN_CART table:
I have written following code fragment to insert the bean data to the table:

```
     ResultSet rs=null;
     String sql="INSERT INTO TRN_CART VALUES (?,?,?,?)"; 
     PreparedStatement ps=useCon.prepareStatement(sql);
     for(ItemBean beanObj: sessionList){
        ps.setString(1, beanObj.getItemId());
        ps.setString(2, beanObj.getItemName());
        ps.setInt(3, beanObj.getItemPrice());
        ps.setInt(4, beanObj.getItemQuantity());
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs==null){           // If any query row execution fails
           returnFlag=false;    // I want to load error page thus setting flag as false
           }
```

I am not sure if I am validating result set in correct way. 
Please suggest me a better way to perform this task.
Also I want to set return flag to be **true if all the row insertion succeeds**.
Suggest me modifications.

Comment: An `INSERT` doesn't return a `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ResultSet is use for select queries but you are inserting.Use `executeUpdate()` for inserting or deleting or updating(DDL commands)

Also `excuteUpdate()` returns integer so if you want to check whether datas are inserted in the database or not then do `if(ps.executeUpdate()>0)`

Comment: I used if(ps.executeQuery()!=null){
 returnFlag=false;
} still that doesnt seem to be a correct way. suggest me solution please

Comment: @RupeshAgrahari you do not have any select quries then why resultSet

Comment: So by using if(ps.executeQuery(sql))  can I achieve the task??

Comment: @RupeshAgrahari no not possible

Comment: @RupeshAgrahari As JqueryLearner pointed out, you should use `executeUpdate()` and examine the returned `int` value to check whether any rows were inserted. Why do you insist on using `executeQuery()`?

Comment: @RupeshAgrahari try if(ps.executeUpdate()>0){ returnFlag=false; } and let me know if you have any other doubts